# sending formdata through POST throws an error at second time

Tags: node.js, forms, express, post

I am making `item list` that I can add items into a `data.json` file from `input:text`.
`nodejs` will receive `POST` request and store `formdata` into `data.json`.

1. `input:text` and `submit` button are inside `form`.
2. I put some text in `input:text`.
3. click submit `button` and `addEventListener` has `e.preventDefault()`. so page won't refresh.
4. nodejs receives `POST` request then function `itemManager` will deal with `formdata` and run `writeFile` and `readFile`.

That's my logic but this won't work at second button click.
At second button click, page will show me this picture.

[image]

`router.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const itemController = require('../controllers/itemController');

router.get('/', itemController);
router.post('/', itemController);

module.exports = router;
```

`itemController.js`

```
const fs = require('fs');

function itemManager(req, res) {

    console.log(Object.keys(req.body).length);

    if (Object.keys(req.body).length) {
        console.log(req.body);
        let json = JSON.stringify(req.body);
        json = json + "\n";

        fs.writeFile('./data/data.json', json, {
            encoding: "utf-8",
            flag: "a+"
        }, (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            else {
                console.log(`success!`);
            }
        });
    }
    fs.readFile('./data/data.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) res.render('index');
        else {
            const dataArray = data.split('\n');
            dataArray.pop();
            for (let i in dataArray) {
                dataArray.push(JSON.parse(dataArray.shift()));
            }
            console.log(`data Array!!!!! : `, dataArray);
            res.render('index', {dataArray});
        }
    })

}
module.exports = itemManager;
```